# Remove duplicates from a string

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, duplicates

Say I have a string like this:

```
anxxnbddc
```

I want to process this and return a string which contains only the characters which appear in the input string exactly once. Therefore my expected output would be:

```
abc
```

I have tried this code:

```
static string RemoveDuplicates(string key)
{
    string result = "";


    for (int i = 0; i < key.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (key[i] != key[i + 1])
        {

            result += key[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

but my output is:

```
anxnbd
```

How do I get my desired output?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and what is not working?

Comment: `var input = "anxxnbddc"; var result = input.Where(c1 => input.Count(c2 => c2 == c1) == 1);`

Comment: @blake this results only the type and not the string "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Char]"

Comment: That's because its still an IEnumerable, you can make it a string with `new string(input.Where(c1 => input.Count(c2 => c2 == c1) == 1).ToArray());`

Answer (score 1):

```
string noDuplicates = new string(input.ToCharArray().Where(c => input.ToCharArray().FindAll(x => x == c).Length == 1).ToArray());
```

Answer (score -2):

Do this with Linq approach:

```
string withoutDuplicates= new string(yourString.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray());
```

Must help

Comment: That was my first thought, but they want to remove the letters that are duplicated. This method will leave an `x` and a `d` in the result.

Comment: @David this returns all without removing duplicates

Comment: I forget sorry: new string(YourString.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray()); I checked and it works

Comment: That still includes all of the duplicate characters. This produces "anxbdc" but the desired result is "abc".

Comment: Blake Thingstad, please check propertly, it will return "anxbdc", aaa ok< I read question not propertly sorry

Comment: `var input = "anxxnbddc"; string withoutDuplicates = new string(input.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray()); foreach (var s in withoutDuplicates) Console.Write(s);` In the console is "anxbdc" after running this.